# ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

**Unable to Start the deployed war file.
I got the following error at the terminal**

```
[ERROR] 17:23:17 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blPersistenceUnitManager' while setting bean property 'persistenceUnitManager'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blMergedDataSources' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'webDS' while setting bean property 'sourceMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [jdbc/web], target type [null]];
```

The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

**Context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<ResourceLink global="jdbc/web" name="jdbc/web" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>


</Context>
```

**Server.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>

    <Resource auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    initialSize="5" 
    maxActive="120" 
    maxIdle="5" 
    maxWait="5000" 
    name="jdbc/web" 
    username="root" 
    password="admin123" 
    poolPreparedStatements="true" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf" 
    validationQuery="select 1"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>

   <Service name="Catalina">
      <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

      <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
      <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
      <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

         <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">

         </Host>
      </Engine>
  </Service>
 </Server>
```

Thank you for your valuable advice. I have edited the post with server.xml and context.xml.

I am following broadleafcommerce's tutorial [http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started].

In order to configure **Switching to MySql** I have made changes as in this link [http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/getting-started-tutorials/switch-to-mysql-tutorial]

**applicationContext-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="org.broadleafcommerce.common.web"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.service.login"/>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.heatclinic.sample" />

<!-- Turn on AOP annotations (required by Broadleaf) -->
<aop:config/>


<bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.catalog.ProductHandlerMapping">
  <property name="order" value="2"/>
</bean>


<bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.web.PageHandlerMapping">
  <property name="order" value="3"/>
</bean>


<bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.catalog.CategoryHandlerMapping">
  <property name="order" value="4"/>
</bean>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.heatclinic.controller" />


<mvc:annotation-driven/>



<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.interceptor.NonResourceWebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="blLocaleCode"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>


<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafCookieLocaleResolver" />


<mvc:resources order="-10" location="/img/, classpath:/common_style/img/" mapping="/img/**" />
<mvc:resources order="-10" location="/fonts/, classpath:/common_style/fonts/" mapping="/fonts/**" />
<mvc:resources order="-10" location="WEB-INF/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="-10" />
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/js/**">blJsResources</prop>
            <prop key="/css/**">blCssResources</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Set up the view resolver to be used by Spring -->
<bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="blWebTemplateEngine" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="cache" value="${thymeleaf.view.resolver.cache}" />
    <property name="fullPageLayout" value="layout/fullPageLayout" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="layoutMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="account/" value="layout/accountLayout" />
            <entry key="catalog/" value="NONE" />
            <entry key="checkout/" value="layout/checkoutLayout" />
            <entry key="checkout/confirmation" value="layout/fullPageNoNavLayout" />
            <entry key="layout/" value="NONE" />
            <entry key="content/NONE" value="NONE" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="blShippingInfoFormValidator" class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.checkout.validator.USShippingInfoFormValidator" />

</beans>
```

Even though I have added **hibernate-3.2.7.ga.jar** file to the lib directory, I get this exception -ClassLoadingException:Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] .

```
[ERROR] 11:09:39 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blEntityManagerFactorySecureInfo' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: blSecurePU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: blSecurePU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory ....

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect ...

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect ] ....

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect ...
```

But the jar file do have the class.

```
3576 Wed Jun 03 16:19:06 PDT 2009 org/hibernate/dialect/MckoiDialect.class
5326 Wed Jun 03 16:19:06 PDT 2009 org/hibernate/dialect/MimerSQLDialect.class
595 Wed Jun 03 16:19:06 PDT 2009 org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5Dialect.class
648 Wed Jun 03 16:19:06 PDT 2009 org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5InnoDBDialect.class
9682 Wed Jun 03 16:19:06 PDT 2009 org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.class
642 Wed Jun 03 16:19:06 PDT 2009 org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLInnoDBDialect.class
544 Wed Jun 03 16:19:06 PDT 2009 org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLMyISAMDialect.class
```

And also I have not mentioned anything about the **hibernate dependencies in the pom.xml** file.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.heatclinic</groupId>
<artifactId>ecommerce-website</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>ecommerce</name>
<url>http://www.blc-archetype.com</url>
<properties>
    <blc.version>3.1.8-GA</blc.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<description>My Company's eCommerce Website</description>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>public snapshots</id>
        <name>public snapshots</name>
        <url>http://nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>generate</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.3,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        build-helper-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.7,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            timestamp-property
                                        </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        keytool-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.5,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>clean</goal>
                                        <goal>generateKeyPair</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
                <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                    <filesets>

                        <fileset>
                            <directory>target</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <toolsjar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</toolsjar>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mac-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <toolsjar>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</toolsjar>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Activated by the profiles above for the paths to tools.jar-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>[1.6,)</version>
           <scope>system</scope>
           <systemPath>${toolsjar}</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.heatclinic</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Broadleaf libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-common</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-profile</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-profile-web</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-framework-web</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-admin-module</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-contentmanagement-module</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-open-admin-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
            <version>${blc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.9</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.30</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<modules>
    <module>admin</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>site</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

I don't find the file named **applicationContext-servlet-cms-contentClient.xml** in the project.

Comment: Sounds like you should search for all the questions with "Name jdbc is not bound in this Context" in them - you haven't told us anything about your configuration, which makes it fairly hard to help you.

Comment: provide configuration details with **blPersistenceUnitManager** bean reference class, to understand the issue.

Comment: From which file do I get this configuration details.

Comment: Is webDS your datasource? If so let's see that. This sounds like a JNDI name mismatch.

Comment: Yes, webDS is the datasource

Comment: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"......
    ......
    ......

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="webDS" jndi-name="jdbc/web"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="webSecureDS" jndi-name="jdbc/secure"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="webStorageDS" jndi-name="jdbc/storage"/>
    
</beans>

Comment: @atishshimpi
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager':Injection of resource dependencies failed; org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blMergedDataSources' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'webDS' while setting bean property 'sourceMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [jdbc/web], target type [null]]; org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'webDS':Invocation of init method failed;

Comment: Your server is what, Tomcat?

Comment: @BillFromHawaii Yes Tomcat Version 6

Comment: Great - let me see your server.xml and context.xml (which will be in tomcat/conf) and go ahead and re-post your spring xml. Please edit your original post instead of posting as a comment as the formatting will be much nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish you'd posted your xml for your spring configuration so I could see if there were any more issues but at the very least you'll need to define **all** your jndi names in tomcat - in server.xml as a `<resource />` in `<globalnames />` and context.xml as `<resourcelink />` in the `<context />` tag. Server.xml will look something like this (you will need to select proper setting for the type of db your using):

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    initialSize="5" 
    maxActive="120" 
    maxIdle="5" 
    maxWait="5000" 
    name="jdbc/web" 
    username="user" 
    password="password" 
    poolPreparedStatements="true" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" 
    validationQuery="select 1"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Although don't delete resources already defined. And this in context.xml:

```
<context>    
   <ResourceLink global="jdbc/web" name="jdbc/web" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</context>
```

I don't want to get dunned for including a link but if you search "tomcat jndi datasource how to" I think you'll find at least one thorough example of what's needed. You'll also need to include the jar containing your driver (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in this example) in tomcat/lib.

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: Thank You. I'm pleased to see your suggestions.But unfortunately it did't help me. I have also included mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar in  tomcat/lib.

Comment: Is there anything to add more(like driver className, url etc) in context.xml ?

Comment: 1) are you using MySql? 2) please add your spring config xml to your post.

Comment: Yes I am using MySql.

Comment: Please add these things to your post: applicationContext-servlet.xml and applicationContext-servlet.xml

Comment: Thank You sir. Your answer helped me. 

I have updated my post with the applicationContext-servlet.xml and updated server.xml & context.xml

Comment: I am sorry I missed asking you for this: applicationContext-servlet-cms-contentClient.xml  and the pom.xml please.

Comment: Also - it seems clear that the JNDI naming error no longer is an issue - Please accept my answer.

Comment: I could not find applicationContext-servlet-cms-contentClient.xml in the project.

Comment: Sajith - you should submit a new question at this point. You should include the pom.xml, the stacktrace, your web.xml, all *.xml where spring beans are defined and your hibernate config xml. If any of your spring config is done with a java config class, include it. My I point out right now that your pom.xml contains no hibernate dependencies.

Comment: Thank You Bill. Should I update my pom.xml with hibernate dependencies?

Can you please share your mail ID so that I can send files through mail.

Comment: Its BillFromHawaii@gmail.com.  And if you're doing that send every xml you have.

Comment: Please check your mail. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got answer to my question. Adding **hibernate dependencies** to my **pom.xml** did the trick. Also don't forget to add hibernate jar(hibernate-3.2.7.ga.jar) file to lib directory.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I think adding the above code resolved the ClassLoadingException:Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect]  which was mentioned in my post.

Answers from Bill fixed JNDI naming error.